# Javascript - trigger actions or events?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, triggers

I want to trigger any possible user actions on given element, like for example: `click, focus, mouseup, mousedown, keyup, keydown, etc...`

Is that like this:

```
element.onclick();
element.onfocus();
element.onsubmit();
element.onmouseover();
element.onkeyup();
element.onkeydown();
```

Or there is something better to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Please learn first what all these methods actually do...

Comment: The first three actually trigger actions, and 2/3 of them trigger events. The last three call functions with those names, which are event handlers but which don’t necessarily exist and aren’t necessarily the only ones, and they don’t perform associated actions (e.g. actually activating a link, button, etc., focusing an element, or submitting a form). The first three are right sometimes and I’d go so far as to say the last three are always wrong.

Comment: @RohitKumar thanks, modified question ;)

Comment: @minitech thank you sorry for that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simulate user's generated mouse events (like clicks) you shoud to something like:

```
<div id="someID" onclick="alert('a');">
  test
</div>
<script>
var theElement = document.getElementById('someID')
 , triggerEvent = function triggerEvent(event, element) {
     var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
     evObj.initEvent(event, true, true);
     element.dispatchEvent(evObj);
 };

 triggerEvent('click', theElement);
</script>
```

Basically you generate an event from the element and let the handlers handle that. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) the list of events.

Hope this could help.

Comment: Hey this looks awesome, i think i will use this !

Answer (score 1):

There's various `onevent` properties on elements that are possibly functions, and you could call them, but in doing so, you'd be be routing around the DOM event handling system. You'd have to pass the proper Event objects to the functions yourself, and they would not automatically bubble up to parent elements.

I'm not sure what'd happen if the element's event was set with `addEventListener` and you tried to calling its `onevent` function directly.

So continue using the methods like `HTMLElement.prototype.click` and `HTMLElement.prototype.focus`. They handle all of that for you.

Comment: *"I'm not sure what'd happen if the element's event was set with `addEventListener` and you tried to calling its `onevent` function directly."* The `onevent` function would be called, but the events attach by `addEventListener` would not be.

Comment: Futhermore, unrelated to the answer, I would just pretend the `onevent` properties don't exist. We have `addEventListener("event", fn, false)` which works better.

Comment: @Havvy thank you, i just preferred the other solution but this was good the same imho